# Difficulties with constructing a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

This is what I have so far on profile on some site:

> Software engineer with more than 12 years of experience in programming
>   and more then 7 years of experience in developing enterprise level applications. Focused on developing highly scalable solutions to complex problems and providing high-quality code.
>
> Leading a team of 7 developers over the last 3 years, developed
>   management system for the State Treasury. 500,000 lines of code were produced with database around 1TB size and tables over 1,000,000,000 rows.

And the concrete problems I have:

1. "highly scalable solutions to complex problems" - is this correct?
2. In the second part I want to say that during last 3 years I was working as a team lead and as a result 500... lines of code were written and the database that was created reached the size 1TB and in that database there are some tables in which there are more then 1000... rows.

Comment: This is kind of borderline proofreading, and may well be closed. Can you focus a little more on specific concerns you have about those two problems?

Comment: Looks idiomatic to me, but you want to say "more than" not "more then".

Comment: @TRomano, thank for spotting that. Also I use `500,000 lines of code were produced`. Is this correct? Were or was? In programming we say 'lines of code' and not 'lines of codes'. So I am stuck what to use there.

Comment: Hint 500,000 > 1. It's the 'lines' not the 'code'.

Comment: Ten bucket*s* of paint *were* used.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for a site like Lang-8,  or at least edited to emphasize specific grammar points OP is having trouble with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. "highly scalable solutions to complex problems" - is this correct?

It's perfect.

> 2. In the second part [...]
>      500,000 lines of code were produced with database around 1TB size and tables over 1,000,000,000 rows.

The passive voice is disrecommended for resumés, and this is in the style of a resumé, so I would change it from "lines of code were produced" to either "team produced 500,000 lines of code" or "Project consisted of 500,000 lines of code."

The phrase "with database around 1TB size" is not good English grammar or style.  There normally needs to be an article in front of "database", though it's sometimes left out on resumés.  But it would be more typical to just write "a 1TB database".  In English we like our adjectives and things that work like adjectives in front of our nouns.

Similarly, "tables over 1,000,000,000 rows" needs a preposition in there: "tables **of** over 1,000,000,000 rows".

I would likely write the whole thing: *My team produced 500,000 lines of code, managing a 1TB database with multiple tables of over 1,000,000,000 rows.*

That's assuming that by "and tables over 1,000,000,000 rows" you meant (it is unclear, as you wrote it) you have multiple tables with more than 1 billion rows, and not tables *totaling between them* 1 billion rows.  If you meant the latter, I would express that: *My team produced 500,000 lines of code, managing a 1TB database of over 1,000,000,000 rows.*

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the passive-voice "lines of code were produced," I'd suggest:

Team produced 500,000 lines of code *for* a database that grew to 1TB, *with* over 1,000,000,000 rows.

(I'd be more interested in how many lines of code you threw away. But that's just me.)